# Can't get border to go on all 4 sides of a screenshot in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have inserted a screenshot, then went to Format Picture to add a border.
 It worked great for the first one, but the second one only shows the border on 3 sides.  It is not appearing on the bottom. I have tried everything but no luck.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Is the bottom of the image overflowing into the page margins? That might prevent formatting from appearing. Try to scale or crop the image down and then apply the border, if that works you will have to leave the image that way, or decrease your page margins.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not impacted by margins, but that's a great thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to appear by right clicking on the picture, text wrap and select square.

Comment: Yes, this is an answer to the question. If you feel it's a wrong answer, downvote it, but do not recommend it to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The missing border might just be invisible at your current display magnification but actually be there. Try zooming in and see if it appears -- or print it out and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by making the border's line width 2pt.

For widths smaller than that (e.g., 1 or 1.5), the bottom line did not reliably appear.